# second harmonic dominant effect, why does it happen?

Tags: fft

I was reading some internal documentation about pump flow pulsations and the following note was written:

> For a given pump, the frequency Fp of those pressure pulsations is
> proportional to its revolution speed of the pump engine n and to its
> piston number zp.
> \begin{align}
>        F_p &= \frac{n * z_p }{60}
> \end{align}
> Note: depending on the hydraulic circuit, the second harmonic may have a dominant effect on the pressure
> pulsations.

for an example of about 400Hz the following image was provided:

signal:
[image]
harmonics:
[image]

Now, i fully understand how the image matches the note declaration but i don't quite catch why the second harmonic is dominant instead of the first one.

I'm not interested in the hydraulics interpretation of it as much as the mathematical interpretation of the harmonics.

Comment: Why did you expect the fundamental to be dominant? The fundamental could even be completely absent.

Comment: aren't all the following harmonics 'multiples' of the fundamental one?

Comment: That's right, but you could have just $2f_0$ and $3f_0$ without $f_0$ being present. The frequency of the corresponding periodic signal would stll be $f_0$.

Comment: now i see it, it relates to the fact the they must be integer multiples so the fundamental, present or not, must be the LCD

Comment: [This answer](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/89375/4298) discusses exactly that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> mathematical interpretation of the harmonics.

That is easy enough: Any function that's periodic with $T$, i.e. $x(t) = x(t + kT), k \in \mathbb{Z}$ can be represented as a sum of sine/cosines, i.e.

$$x(t) = \sum_k a_k \cos(k\frac{2\pi}{T} + \varphi_k) $$

There is no restrictions on what value the amplitudes can take, so any value is valid including $a_k = 0$ for any k including the fundamental (k = 1) (other than some esoteric exceptions which would change the period)

> I'm not interested in the hydraulics interpretation

You should be. The distribution of the harmonics is determined by the underlying physical process

> why the second harmonic is dominant instead of the first one.

Because that's how the pump works. There is no mathematical reason why it should be one way or the other. The driving mechanism are the physics not the math.

Comment: i thought that the fundamental should inherently dictate the shape and the others just distort it in some measure, but it was based on nothing apparently, isn't it?

Comment: as per the `i'm not interested in the pump physics part` i put it just because i cannot share even wanting the underlying model due to privacy policies. It was more a disclaimer to say that i'm not searching an explanation on the hydraulics part but just on signal itself

Comment: @FerroLuca I understand. All I'm saying is:  the answer to your questions is "it's the physics not the math". The fundamental does NOT inherently dictate the shape: in fact it can (and is) totally absent. Case in point is old-style telephone: the bandwidth is 300-3400 Hz which specifically exclude the fundamental range of the human voice. That changes the tonal quality but not the pitch,

Answer (score 2):

Either the values in the harmonics plot are the harmonics of the waveform different from what you show in the signal plot, or, because of the calculating/plotting inconsistency, the frequency axis in the harmonics plot is scaled 2:1 with respect to a true frequency variable. The mismatch of the signal waveform and the harmonics presented in the question can be discovered by inspection.

By definition (Wikipedia article Periodic_function),

> A function f is said to be periodic if, for some nonzero constant P, it is the case that

> f(x+P)=f(x)

> for all values of x in the domain. A nonzero constant P for which this is the case is called a period of the function. If there exists a least positive constant P with this property, it is called the fundamental period (also primitive period, basic period, or prime period.)

Admitting that the signal plot can look rough because of pixelation limitation aggravated by small signal irregularities (noise), I use yellow marker to mark some of the ranges covering "the fundamental period" of your signal. The width of these ranges, P, is 25ms.

[image: signal_period]

If the signal were the pure sinusoidal wave with the period P, it would have exactly one harmonic at 400Hz. In your harmonics plot, the first noticeable peak is at 800Hz, the second, at 1600Hz, and the third, at 2400Hz. Theoretically, these peaks can represent 2nd, 4th and 6th harmonics, with the fundamental frequency of 400Hz.

To declare that the fundamental frequency value is 400Hz from only seeing the harmonics plot, one must make sure that there exists at least one odd harmonic at larger frequencies.

If there are only even harmonics, the signal waveform is not different then a realization of pure 800Hz waveform, and what we call 2nd, 4th and 6th harmonics are in fact 1st, 2nd and 3rd harmonics. But the period of the 800 Hz waveform is 12.5ms, in contrast to what we see by inspection.

As searching over the entire spectrum for the odd harmonics of the 400Hz waveform might be problematic, one can try more informal approach. We can simulate your waveform with the finite expression and examine the Fourier transform of this simulated waveform.

Composed mainly of two sinusoidal waves of frequencies fp = 400Hz and 2fp = 800Hz, plus a sinusoidal wave of frequency 3fp = 1200Hz to account for the small third peak of your harmonics plot, the waveform $\text{pulsations} = 2.4·\sin(2\pi f_p t) + 2.4·\sin(2\pi((2 f_p) t + 2/9)) + 0.15·\sin(2\pi (3 f_p) t)$:

[image: pulsations]

looks similar to your signal, and, no wonder, the Fourier transform of this waveform gives harmonics at 400Hz, 800Hz and 1200Hz, exactly halves of the bin frequencies 800Hz, 1600Hz and 2400Hz shown in your harmonics plot.

[image: harmonics]

Harmonic amplitudes also appear to be different, although this apparent difference can be explained by pixelation of narrow peaks in your plot picture, your specific definition of harmonic amplitude, etc. Only you have necessary information to delve deeper.

The comparison of the "harmonics" plots, one of your question and another calculated for the waveform similar to that of your question (image above), is a valid argument for my initial claim that the frequency axis in your harmonics plot is scaled 2:1 with respect to a true frequency variable. With correctly plotted "harmonics" graph, the main contributor to the pressure pulsations would become the first (400Hz), not second (800Hz), harmonic, and yours is not the hydraulic circuit covered by the note from `some internal documentation about pump flow pulsations`.